# C# Interop loop through values received from a range

Tags: c#, interop

How can I loop through the values that are returned from a specified range?

I tried the following code but it returns:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Array'

```
var rng = (Excel.Range)sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[3, 2], sheet.Cells[3, 27]];
var wsValues = rng.Cells.Value;
for (var j = 0; j < wsValues.Length; j++)
{
    var test = wsValues[j];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a system array not a 'normal array' (based upon the error).  So you should be able to use `var test = wsValues.GetValue(1, j);`  Note this will return an object.  So you will have to do a cast to your expected type.

Also note that the 1 in that case is because all your test data has 1 as your first value in your multidimensional array.  You can view a multidimensional array as a grid, with an x co-ordinate and a y co-ordinate, so if you wanted to iterate through them properly (as if you were using up multiple columns instead of just one).  Then you would do:

```
for (var x = 1; x <= wsValues.GetLength(0); x++)
{
    for (var y = 1; y <= wsValues.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
        var test = wsValues[x, y];
    }
}
```

In this the GetLength command returns the length of that dimension, so the first one returns the length of how many 'columns' or the maximum x value there are, and the second one returns the maximum y value or how many rows there are.

Comment: Tried with `var test = wsValues.GetValue(j)` and it returns: `Array was not a one-dimensional array.`

Comment: That's because its a multidimensional array, I'll edit my answer to give a proper lookup.

Comment: Now I get `Index was outside the bounds of the array.` for `x=0`, `y=0`

Comment: Sorry, by adding the code I was hoping you would see that in your example your x = 0, and y = 0 aren't valid (through your supplied test), so that you would have to start the counters at 1.  That's okay though I'll edit answer.

Comment: Mhmm thats odd are you sure you also made it do a <= since you are starting at 1?  As shown in answer?